# Tensorflow in Android: How do i use my linear regression model to predict a value in an android application?

Tags: java, android, python-3.x, tensorflow, linear-regression

I currently have a ipynb file (ipython notebook) that contains a linear regression code / model(im not entirely sure if it's a model) that I've created earlier.

How do i implement this model in an android application such that if I were to input a value of 'x' in a text box, it'll output in a textview the predicted value of 'y'. Function: Y = mx + b.

I've tried looking at different tutorials, but they were mostly not "step-by-step" guides, which made it really hard to understand, I'm a beginner at coding.

Here's my code for the model:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
rng = np.random

from numpy import genfromtxt
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston

# Parameters
learning_rate = 0.0001
training_epochs = 1000
display_step = 50
n_samples = 222

X = tf.placeholder("float") # create symbolic variables
Y = tf.placeholder("float")

filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(["C://Users//Shiina//battdata.csv"],shuffle=False)
reader = tf.TextLineReader() # skip_header_lines=1 if csv has headers
key, value = reader.read(filename_queue)

# Default values, in case of empty columns. Also specifies the type of the
# decoded result.
record_defaults = [[1.], [1.]]
height, soc= tf.decode_csv(
    value, record_defaults=record_defaults)
features = tf.stack([height])

# Set model weights
W = tf.Variable(rng.randn(), name="weight")
b = tf.Variable(rng.randn(), name="bias")

# Construct a linear model
pred_soc = tf.add(tf.multiply(height, W), b) # XW + b <- y = mx + b  where W is gradient, b is intercept

# Mean squared error
cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(pred_soc-soc, 2))/(2*n_samples)

# Gradient descent
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)

# Initializing the variables
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
# Start populating the filename queue.
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)
    sess.run(init)

     # Fit all training data
    for epoch in range(training_epochs):
        _, cost_value = sess.run([optimizer,cost])

        #Display logs per epoch step
    if (epoch+1) % display_step == 0:
        c = sess.run(cost)
        print( "Epoch:", '%04d' % (epoch+1), "cost=", "{:.9f}".format(c), \
            "W=", sess.run(W), "b=", sess.run(b))

    print("Optimization Finished!")
    training_cost = sess.run(cost)
    print ("Training cost=", training_cost, "W=", sess.run(W), "b=", sess.run(b), '\n')

#Plot data after completing training
    train_X = []
    train_Y = []
    for i in range(n_samples): #Your input data size to loop through once
        X, Y = sess.run([height, pred_soc]) # Call pred, to get the prediction with the updated weights
        train_X.append(X)
        train_Y.append(Y)

    #Graphic display

    plt.plot(train_X, train_Y, 'ro', label='Original data')
    plt.ylabel("SoC")
    plt.xlabel("Height")
    plt.axis([0, 1, 0, 100])
    plt.plot(train_X, train_Y, linewidth=2.0)
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()

    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)
```

Comment: How familiar are you with Java/ Android Development?

Comment: I'm a beginner that just started learning this month.

Comment: RIght ok. I've done basically zero Android work apart from some minor changes to the Tensorflow Demo Application Suite. If you've not looked at those yet then perhaps have a look through. See this link on how to implement the Tensorflow library in Java/ANdroid and I imagine you'll want to use the Java API/jar centre stuff to implement in Android. Not really sure why you'd want a linear regressor in android like that, especially if you are trying to train (not really recommended for android devices.) See more here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/android